# Talend could not parse column as timestamp

Tags: mysql, mariadb, talend

I need your help in this issue,

I have a talend job which load data from a table to another with a simple tmap.

I called it a mysterious error because it happended just for a specific datetimes

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not parse column as timestamp, was: "2009-06-01 00:00:00"
```

Thousands of rows before the row containing this line doesn't generate the error

When I modify this date     **2009-06-01 00:00:00**     to another or just changing the day part or the month or even the hour, It goes **without error.**

the datasource is a **mariadb** and the destination is a **Mysql** database

thnks for your help

[image]
[image]

[image]

and this is the part of code which contain the error generated

```
                    if (colQtyInRs_tMysqlInput_5 < 6) {
                        row5.created_at = null;
                    } else {

                        if (rs_tMysqlInput_5.getString(6) != null) {
                            String dateString_tMysqlInput_5 = rs_tMysqlInput_5
                                    .getString(6);
                            if (!("0000-00-00")
                                    .equals(dateString_tMysqlInput_5)
                                    && !("0000-00-00 00:00:00")
                                            .equals(dateString_tMysqlInput_5)) {
                                row5.created_at = rs_tMysqlInput_5
                                        .getTimestamp(6);
                            } else {
                                row5.created_at = (java.util.Date) year0_tMysqlInput_5
                                        .clone();
                            }
                        } else {
                            row5.created_at = null;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Ok, this is a first step. Now, how does the export schema look like?

Comment: the export schema is exactly the same schema of source

Comment: Then I suppose this error comes from one of the tWarns which wants to tell you something went wrong.

Comment: the error comes when loading data to tmap, so I got a java error with my tDie message

Comment: tDie? Does the job end? Still not clear where exactly this error comes from. We haven't seen the input component schema. Is the source data type also a date or maybe a VARCHAR?

Comment: You can find attached a screen of the input schema. Yes the job end when coming to the row with the date I have mentioned

Comment: Usually there is a stack trace as well and you could look up the specific row in code which throws this error.

Comment: the line of code which throws this error is : .getTimestamp(6)

Comment: Well, only this line without the context is a bit less helpful. Maybe copy the surrounding 30 lines from top and bottom and post it in your question?

Comment: Done, I added the code in my question

Comment: Seems correct like that... Hmm. And this is definitely from the orders table and not from the log_orders?

Comment: Yes sure, cauz I deleted log_orders and I did just a simple job with input tmap output , and still have the same problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to Timezone, after trying many solutions, I thought about changing the timezone because My Laptop is in UTC and the database timezone is UTC+01 so Talend generate this error in local environment.
Hope it will help someone else

Answer (score 0):

Since you provided no further information in

- How the source data looks like, e.g. is it a date field or a string field in the source?
- Why parsing would happen, this seems to be connected to the source data being a string
- How the parsing pattern looks like

I am going to assume a bit here.

**1st**: I assume you provide a string in the source. Since this is the case, you'd need to make sure that the date in the column is always formatted the same way. Also, you'd need to show us the timestamp format for parsing.

**2nd**: You said you'd need to change the values of the date for it to work. This seems to me to be an issue with parsing, so for example you have switched by accident the month and day field, e.g. `yyyy-dd-mm HH:mm:ss` or something alike. Again, this depends on your parsing string.

Since there is often a bit of confusion about this [I created a blog post for date handling in Talend](https://www.tobiasmaasland.de/2017/07/20/using-date-in-talend-etl-jobs/) which you could consult as well.

Comment: Hi, the field is a datetime and the pattern is "yyyy-MM-dd" and as I said, it works for thousands of rows except this datetime 2009-06-01 00:00:00 and some others

Comment: Well, if the field is a date field already then the pattern doesn't matter. I recommend reading up the blog post. Which others don't work? How does the job look like? How do the input and the output components look like?

Comment: the job contains a mysqlinput --> tmap --> mysqloutput , simple job, with some lookups for joins

Comment: Ok, I meant pictures of the actual components since the infos you provided are not sufficient. It is not possible to see the data types, the patterns, even source data should be added.

Comment: Done, I added the job used components and the tmap, tell me if you need more informations plz